# Jquery drag and drop switch draggable element for new one

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm really new to Jquery. I have been asked to make some drag and drop functionality. I have managed to find many resources that lead me to a simple result. 
( http://jsfiddle.net/TgQTP/14/ ).

What is missing is that i would like for a switch functionality.
Example:
When dragging the blue square over a '.droppable' that already has another square appended (X), i would like for the blue to substitute X and make X return to a specific place. X can return with an animation or just by appending it.

My problem here is that don't know how to make that "switch".

Comment: You say you want to "make X return to a specific place." Does that mean you want blue to always go back to blue's original position, or just back to the original color bank? Here's how the latter can be done: http://jsfiddle.net/xWZcj/ Let me know if you're looking for the former.

Comment: $('.ui-draggable', this) this was what i was missing. I was always doing $(this).draggable thinking i would reach the ui.draggable object. If i want an animation should i use .animate or try the revert of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the drag, drop, and switch using this in your jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/TgQTP/14/):

```
$('.draggable').each(function(index, div) {

    var scope = $(this).attr('data-scope');

    $(div).draggable({

        stop: function() {

            $('.droppable').droppable('option', 'disabled', false);

        },

        helper: 'clone'

    });

});

$('.droppable').droppable({      

    drop: function(event, ui) {

        var x = $(this).find('.draggable');

        if (! ($(this).attr('id') === 'bank')) {

            if (! x.length){

                $(this).append(ui.draggable);       

            } 

        } else {

            $('#bank').append($('.ui-draggable', this));

            $(this).append(ui.draggable);

        }            
    }

});
```

Full jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xWZcj/

To add an animation on the square switch return, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/xWZcj/1/

You can switch out:

```
$('#bank').append($('.ui-draggable', this).hide().fadeIn(600));
```

To use a variety of other animations provided by jQuery UI (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects) 
​